# Show full command line activity while building\compiling in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for some tool\feature of Visual Studio that would allow me to see all the underlying commands it is executing when it builds and compiles a project.

csc.exe calls with all parameters\switches\options displayed
Tlbimp.ex calls with all parameters\switches\options displayed

etc.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. I'll mark you for answer if you move to answer section.